# Hiding a div or class when my site is accessed via specific URL

Tags: javascript, html, url, show-hide, shopify

I am not using a hosting service, my website is entirely hosted on the shopify platform.

I want to **hide** `class="site-header"` for my website when it is accessed via a domain forward/masking link http://fetchy.ca but have it **displayed/shown** when the website is accessed via http://wetpaintrecords.com.

http://fectchy.ca contains an frameset/frame inside which the element is to be hidden.

Comment: You can use `window.location` and toggle visibility of necessary elements. You can refer following link [Location - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)

Comment: '<script src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1107/8722/files/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script language="text/javascript">
$(function(){
      if (window.location.pathname == "fetchy.ca") {
            $('#header.site-header').hide();
      } else {
            $('#site-header').show();
      }
 });
</script>'

Comment: That is what I was trying but haven't been able to make it work

Comment: `fetchy.ca` is the host name, not the path of the URL.

Comment: Okay, I guess then my question is, is there no way to hide the div class="site-header" if the site was access via the fetchy.ca host name?

Answer (score 0):

try this code it works but i don't know whether it's the best way to approach this kind of problem.

```
<script>
    var url = window.location;
    if(url.toString().indexOf('fetchy.ca') != -1) {
        $('.site-class').hide();
    } else {
        $('.site-class').show();
    }
</script>
```

try that, you first test for the location and then you check whether the url contains the 'domain name' and then hide the 'div' as wanted, but NOTE: when javascript is disabled in the browser for some reason, it won't work...

if you had a backend like php if would've been quite easier i think.

Comment: This didn't work out, I added it to my theme.liquid in shopify but didn't have any luck.

Comment: does that file contain html( can it execute javascript ), because 'window.location' is a global variable representing the global execution context which is the browser, and the 'location' method return the url to the current executing file, so we convert the object to a 'string' and check whether it contains a specific 'string' it should work, i tested it and it worked fine on my localhost.

Comment: <script>
    var url = window.location;
    if(url.toString().indexOf('fetchy.ca') != -1) {
        $('.site-header').hide();
    } else {
        $('.site-header').show();
    }
</script>

Comment: Which file are you referring to?

Comment: theme.liquid is an html file yes

Comment: you know what mate, try to alert(window.location) and see the values returned, we may be targeting the wrong value/string, and by the way how does the above script work in your website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.hostname`:

In the below example, I'm hiding a div and showing another if it is access in JSFiddle.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/u0trv95q/1/).

```js
(function init() {
  if (window.location.hostname === "fiddle.jshell.net") {
    $(".header").hide();
    $(".header_2").show();
  } else {
    $(".header").show();
    $(".header_2").hide();
  }
})()
```

```css
.header {
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ddd;
}
.header_2 {
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="header">Header 1. This is a generic header, shown for all cases.</div>
<div class="header_2">Header 2. Only shown if accessed from JSFiddle</div>
```

You are getting proper value in `window.location.hostname`.

[image]

Comment: Can you check what `window.location` is returning?

Comment: Not an expert with javascript. Not sure how to check what its returning

Comment: In your function, write `console.log("location Object: ", window.location);` and on your page, check the developer console.

Comment: I added the code then hit developer tools in my broswer but still can't find what its returning.

Comment: In developer tools, there is a tab called `Console`. Access that and see the logged value. If not logged, you can even execute it on console.

Comment: So you are getting proper value in `hostname`. right?

Comment: No not really, I'm getting the original site hostname but not what I have set up as a mask URL.

Comment: any other suggestions?

Comment: Try calling this function after document is loaded. **[Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)**. Interesting thing is when you log, DOM is not rendered completely and so masking is not happened. But if you check in console manually, you get proper result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in shopify ***theme.liquid*** or ***index.liquid*** or any other liquid wherever the `class="site-header"`

```
{% if shop.url == 'http://wetpaintrecords.com' or shop.url == 'wetpaintrecords.com' %}
<div ... class="site-header">
.....
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Alternatively add this anywhere in your theme.liquid file

```
{% if shop.url == 'http://fetchy.ca' or shop.url == 'fetchy.ca' %}
<style>
  .site-header{display:none !important;}
</style>
{% endif %}
```

EDIT: OP is using an iframe/frameset/frame, hence the following solution.

You have two options here.

**Option 1 (simplest)** - Add the following in your theme file liquid:

```
{% unless collection %}
<style>
   .site-header{display:none !important;}
</style>
{% endunless %}
```

**Option 2 (not simplest but safest)** - Find the liquid file containing '*header class="site-header" role="banner"*' and change that section to the following:

```
{% unless collection %}
<header class="site-header" role="banner">
..........
</header>
{% endunless %}
```

By this, whenever the page is a collection (artist page as intended), the section will not be displayed.

Comment: Here is a site that has it working in their shopify store. 
Both links go to the same store, one method/url/link shows the top header whereas the other method/url/link does not.

http://store.warnermusic.ca/collections/Brett-Kissel#store 

http://www.warnermusic.ca/store/brettkissel/

Comment: I checked your links - fetchy and wetpaintrecords. the former seems to be an iframe of a collections page in the latter. Server side code will not work that way.

Also at the moment there seems to be no 'site-header' in fetchy.ca

Comment: Yea so what do you suggest is the right way to do it? 
I'm just trying to give each artist the optical illusion of having their very own site and store. The home page is always a collection page. But there are iframe YouTube videos embedded on each home/collection page.

Comment: Ultimately, I'm hoping to give each recording artist we sign to the label,  their very own website,  by simply purchasing a domain and hiding the record label's main navigation menu seen at the top of the page when they access the site via the artists' domain name versus the record label domain. So far we have these. Domains for the artists: fetchy.ca freshcitymusic.com troyjunker.com

Comment: What you are trying to do is "wrong" in Shopify sense. You'll have a ton of CORS errors if you do it that way. What's wrong with using collection links? Other possible issues include SEO headaches. Do you want to go through all that? If yes read the edits in my answer.

Comment: The issue with it hiding for all "collections" is that there are collections on our store such as "accessories", "music", and "apparel". These "collections" require the site navigation, which we are subsequently hiding. And not all of the pages for artists are "collections" either, some are "pages". "Collections" are used for artist "home" and artist "store" other then that they will be "pages". That's why I originally was looking for a method that could hide it based on the URL. I'm not sure if method 2 with your edits is the best route.

Comment: In that case, for artist collection, create a duplicate template "collection.artists" and set is as collection type as "collection.artists" for artist collections. Then use {% unless collection.template_suffix == 'artists' %} instead of {% unless collection %} in the above code. It'll work.